# NSDateFormatter error, return date one year ago

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Code:

```
NSString *ds = @"2013-02-25";
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:ds];
NSLog(@"%@", date); //2012-02-24 16:00:00 +0000
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]); //Feb 25, 2012
```

Is there something wrong I made? Or iOS 6 SDK bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this :

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY"];
```

To :

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
```

Reason for the error,

> It's a common mistake to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year
>   whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO
>   year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same
>   number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the
>   calendar year.

Comment: @Rushi: Nice explaination. He can accept in 15 min once block time over.